# How to construct such SEM framework with OpenMx or lavaan package in R

Tags: r, modeling, cox-regression, pearson-correlation, statistical-test

Hi well i am clinical scientist and relatively new to R and coding. While studying medical literature, I often come across the SEM frame work diagrams which explains multivariate regression or correlation just in one diagram which is interesting to understand. I am also struggling to formulate one but couldnot sort out. How can i formulate this diagrame from the summary(fit) of following. Can you interpret summary(fit) too??

```
library("lavaan.survey")
install.packages("lavaan.survey")

data("pisa.be.2003")

model.pisa <- "
    math =~ PV1MATH1 + PV1MATH2 + PV1MATH3 + PV1MATH4
    neg.efficacy =~ ST31Q01 + ST31Q02 + ST31Q03 + ST31Q04 + 
                    ST31Q05 + ST31Q06 + ST31Q07 + ST31Q08
    neg.selfconcept =~ ST32Q02 + ST32Q04 + ST32Q06 + ST32Q07 + ST32Q09

    neg.selfconcept ~ neg.efficacy + ESCS + male
    neg.efficacy ~ neg.selfconcept + school.type + ESCS + male
    math ~ neg.selfconcept + neg.efficacy + school.type + ESCS + male
"

fit <- lavaan(model.pisa, data = pisa.be.2003, auto.var = TRUE, std.lv = TRUE,
  meanstructure = TRUE, int.ov.free = TRUE, estimator = "MLM")
summary(fit)
```

[![:ČukićI,BatesTC(2015)TheAssociation betweenNeuroticismandHeartRateVariabilityIsNot FullyExplainedbyCardiovascularDiseaseand Depression.PLoSONE10(5):e0125882. doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0125882
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Wlq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Wlq.png)

Comment: This might be a good place to look for packages: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you are describing:

```
library(lavaanPlot)
lavaanPlot(model = fit, coefs = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is the semPaths from package semPlot:

```
library(semPlot)
semPaths(fit, "std")
```

There are several plot alternatives in the [link](http://sachaepskamp.com/semPlot/examples)